# Evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left[ \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \frac{2}{(n+2)(n+4)} + \cdots + \frac{n}{6n^2} \right]$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, summation, riemann-sum

> Evaluate: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left[ \dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \dfrac{2}{(n+2)(n+4)} + \cdots + \dfrac{n}{6n^2} \right]$$

$\text{My Attempt:}$ breaking down the summation series into: $$\sum_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{r}{(n+r)(n+2r)}$$. 
Further breaking down into two separate series: $$\sum_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{r}{(n+r)(n+2r)}=\sum_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{(n+2r)-(n+r)}{(n+r)(n+2r)}$$
This will reduce to give: $$\sum_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{n+r} - \sum_{r=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{n+2r}$$
Now, applying limits to the sum: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[\sum_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{n+r} -  \sum_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{n+2r}\right]$$
Taking $n$ common in denominator and converting to Definite integral taking $\dfrac{r}{n}=x$ this reduces to: $$\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\text{dx}}{1+x}-\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{\text{dx}}{1+2x}$$

Edit: Solving this we will get the answer as $\ln\left(\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$.

I have had committed an error in the evaluation of the 2nd integral as Mr. Robert Z has pointed out below.

Comment: $$ … = \log 2 - \frac 12 \int_0^1 \frac {\mathrm d(2x+1)} {2x+1} = \log 2 - \frac 12 \log 3, $$ so what happened?

Comment: @xbh Yes, you are right!

Comment: More often than not, textbooks dealing with sufficiently complicated mathematics contain errors in worked examples.

Comment: Another easy way to check is to notice  that $1/(n+r) > 1/(n+2r)$ for all $r \geqslant 1$, so we should get something nonnegative. Thus $\log (2/9) < \log 1 = 0$ is not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After revising my answer, I got: as $n\to \infty$,
$$\begin{align}\sum_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{r}{(n+r)(n+2r)}&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{\frac{r}{n}}{(1+\frac{r}{n})(1+2\frac{r}{n})}\\
&\to \int_0^1 \frac{x}{(1+x)(1+2x)}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{1+2x}\right)\,dx\\
&=\left[\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{(1+2x)^{1/2}}\right)\right]_0^1\\
&= \ln(2/\sqrt{3}).
\end{align}$$
So, your approach is correct, and there is just a minor error in the integration of $1/(1+2x)$.